# Roblox 2009 Lua: Get Loadstring's error

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been making a 2009 script builder for a few hours now, and I can't figure out how to make it print errors. If I do `print(loadstring("a"))` it prints into the roblox output `nil [string "s"]:1: '=' expected near '<eof>'`, which == nil. What I want to get is the error it reports at the end `: '=' expected near '<eof>'`, type type is nil, so I have no idea how to get it. If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the Lua 5.1 manual, which will point you to the documentation for [`load`](https://lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-load):

> If there [are] errors, ... returns nil plus the error message.

It's typical for Lua to return error messages as a second return value:

```
local f, err = loadstring(mycode)
if not f then
    print("There was an error: `" .. err .. "`")
end
```

---

This `err` begins with *where* the error happened, which unhelpfully quotes the input to `loadstring`.

For example, for the input code `"hello there"`, the error is

```
[string "hello there"]:1: '=' expected near 'there'
```

Lua appears to cut the quote off at the first newline or 63 character, whichever is less:

For `"hello\there"` the error is

```
[string "hello..."]:2: '=' expected near 'there'
```

For `"helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo there"` the error is

```
[string "helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo ther..."]:1: '=' expected near 'there'
```

If you're sure there's no `"]:` in the first 63 characters/first line of your script, you can just search for that sequence to find where it stops:

```
local location, message = err:match('^(%[string ".*"%]:%d+:%s+)(.*)$')
```

This won't be right if your code is, for example, `"hello\"]:1: there"`, which you may want to address.

The simplest way to address it would be to take user control away from the first line that is quoted: prepend the code with your own first line that is nice (and make sure to adjust the line number of the error if you display it to the user:)

```
local f, err = loadstring("--code\n" .. mycode)
print(err)
```

Now the error message should always begin

```
[string "--code..."]:
```

Comment: The OP probably wants `err:match(": (.*)")`.

Comment: They said "type is nil", so it appears they don't know about the second return value. But yes, I'll ad a bit about processing the error